# Is there a way to retrieve the language of a phone with Flutter so that the application can detect the default language?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the language of my flutter application by retrieving the default language of the phones set in the preferences. How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

In `MaterialApp` you can set application language with `local` property,
local property by default is system language

if you don't set a custom local, app will use system language if this language is available in your app

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retreive that on the start of the application using [localeResolutionCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/localeResolutionCallback.html) in the MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
                  title: 'SportsTak',
                  home:Home(),
                  localeListResolutionCallback: ( localeOfDevice, listedLocales){
        
                  //Here is what you can loop through listedLocales and compare from localeOfDevice and return the locale you support
                    
                  },
                  supportedLocales:[ ] , //listofsupportedlocales
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use `Platform.localeName` from `dart:io` to get the name of the current device locale.

```
import 'dart:io';

String languageCode = Platform.localeName;
```